# How to do conditional update on a component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I have a JSF composite component which renders only some parts based on the attribute `cc.attrs.list` passed to it. 
In one of the components I want to update a set of other components based on the attribute. So something like this:

```
<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{cc.listener}" 
update="#{cc.attrs.id2}_input #{cc.attrs.id2}_resultTable"/>
```

The problem is that the resultTable is not rendered all the time and when the resultTable is not there, I get an exception `Cannot find component with expression "id_resultTable"`, which is not surprising. So my idea was to create a variable which will contain id of the attribute or empty String like this:

```
<c:if test="#{cc.attrs.list}">
    <ui:param name="updateTable" value="#{cc.attrs.id2}_resultTable"/>
</c:if>
<c:otherwise>
    <ui:param name="updateTable" value=""/>
</c:otherwise>
```

and then do the ajax update like this:

```
 <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{cc.listener}" 
update="#{cc.attrs.id2}_input #{updateTable}"/>
```

The problem is, that the `#{updateTable}` variable is always an empty String(I've tried to put it as a content of outputText) and I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks, but the condition is fine. The ```list``` parameter is defined as this: ```<composite:attribute name="list" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false"/>``` and in other cases it works(I use it to render/not render the components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just omit the `ui:param` and do the check directly in the `p:ajax`:

```
<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{cc.listener}" 
update="#{cc.attrs.id2}_input #{cc.attrs.list ? cc.attrs.id2.concat('_resultTable') : ''}"/>
```

A problem with the `c:if`-approach could be, that when you update this section via ajax the condition is not re-checked as JSTL-tags are evaluated at view build time. Have a look at [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution, but I've done a workaround for the problem which works. I've added `h:panelGroup` with id around the table and I'm updating this instead of the table.